# Asymptotics of $\sum_1^x \mu(n)/n$

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

It is known that $\Bigl|{\sum_1^x \mu(n)/n}\Bigr|\leq 726/\log^2 x$ for $x>1$, reference [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL18/Bordelles2/bordelles21.pdf).

**A**) Is there a result on the l0wer bound $f$ of $\sum_1^x \mu(n)/n$ of the type ${\lim\sup}_{x \to \infty}\Bigl|{\sum_1^x \mu(n)/n}\Bigr|\geq O(f)$?

**B**) Could you please locate the error in the following:

a) $\zeta(s)=\sum_1^\infty 1/n^s$
-- this is true for $Re(s)>1$;
b) $\zeta(1)=\lim_{s \to 1^+}\zeta(s)=\lim_{s \to 1^+}\sum_1^\infty 1/n^s=\sum_1^\infty 1/n$
-- the limit does not exist, but this expression nonetheless describes the pole of zeta at $1$;
c) $\zeta(1)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\sum_1^x 1/n$
-- this seems to follow naturally from b);
d) $\sum_1^x 1/n = H(x)\sim \log x$
-- this is just the definition of a harmonic number $H(x)$ and its well known [asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation);
e) $\zeta(1)\sim\log x$, or, more precisely, $\zeta(1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log x$
-- this simply follows from c) and d);
f) $\sum_1^\infty \mu(n)/n^s=1/\zeta(s)$
-- this is true at least for $Re(s)\geq 1$;
g) $\sum_1^\infty \mu(n)/n=1/\zeta(1)$
-- this doesn't seem problematic, since it follows from f);
h) $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_1^x \mu(n)/n=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_1^x 1/n}$
-- this follows from g) and c);
i) $\sum_1^x \mu(n)/n\sim 1/\log x$
-- this follows from h) and d).

There is an error in here in **B**), because the result i) is in a sharp contrast with the known better result $\Bigl|{\sum_1^x \mu(n)/n}\Bigr|\leq 726/\log^2 x$, $x>1$. Can someone point a finger at the exact location of the error?

Comment: I choose e) as the first error.

Comment: @GEdgar Hi. Any specifics about e) being wrong?

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis would imply that $|\sum_{n < x}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}| = o(x^{-1/2+\epsilon})$, and $|\sum_{n < x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| = \mathcal{O}(x^{-1+a+\epsilon})$ implies that $1/\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic on $Re(s)  > a$, so  $|\sum_{n < x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| > C x^{-1/2-\epsilon}$ infinitely often

Comment: Now this is the answer to A), the rest of your question  is impossible to understand (and full of mistakes)

Comment: @user1952009 Hi. Indeed, but the result involving $x^{-1/2}$ conditionally assumes the truth of RH. Now that I think about it, if anyone would know an unconditional estimate, one would have proven or disproven RH! There will be no unconditional answer to this question I'm affraid.

Comment: Since $1/\zeta(s)$ isn't holomorphic on $Re(s) = 1/2$, unconditionally you have $|\sum_{n < x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| > C x^{-1/2-\epsilon}$ infinitely often. This is because (summing by parts)  $ \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sum_{k \le n} \mu(k)k^{-a}) (n^{a-s}-(n+1)^{a-s})$ more details on [wiki/Dirichlet_series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence)

Comment: @user1952009 Hi, indeed. Why impossible to understand and, importantly, what mistakes exactly?!

Comment: $\zeta(1)$ isn't defined, you can assign $0$ to $1/\zeta(1)$, and  I just wrote the correct estimates for $\sum_{n < x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ (depending on the zero with largest real part of $\zeta(s)$) So again read wiki/Dirichlet_series  and a course on $\zeta(s)$

Comment: You're trying to argue with $\zeta(1)$ as if it were a sort-of-number-not-really-but-stands-for-a-function-of-$x$. That will lead to all kinds of mistakes, and mistakes that are moreover hard for us to actually describe, since you're basing your statements on incorrect assumptions. If you try rewriting your entire argument rigorously, without using self-made notational conventions, I bet you'll find some mistakes yourself.

Comment: @GregMartin Hi. I changed e) so that it more precisely treat zeta(1) as a number, not as a function. Does this change something now?

Comment: @user1952009 Hi. Estimates concern part A). Any concrete thoughts on part B) maybe?

Comment: Yes, it makes a mistake very evident: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \log x$ does not exist. It is not $\zeta(1)$. And $\zeta(1)$ does not exist either (precisely because $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^x 1/n$ does not exist). If you have some sort of renormalization in mind, I urge you to write the actual definition of that renormalization. At present, I don't feel that the notation you're choosing is equipped to separate true arguments from false arguments.

Comment: @GregMartin Hi. Yes, the equation should have read probably $\zeta(s,x)=\sum_1^x 1/n^s $, with $\zeta(1)=\lim_{s\to 1}\lim_{x\to\infty}\zeta(s,x)$. However, I find the question resolved now, thanks to the answer by user1252009. Thanks for useful comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $\mu(n)$ : $$(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \mu(m)m^{-s})(\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-s}) = \sum_{m \ge 1, k \ge 1} (km)^{-s} \mu(m) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) = 1$$

This is true as formal series, and as convergent series only for $Re(s) > 1$.

Now you can write that

$$(\sum_{m=1}^N \mu(m)m^{-s})(\sum_{k=1}^N k^{-s}) = \sum_{1 \le m \le N, 1 \le k \le N} (km)^{-s} \mu(m)$$ $$ = \sum_{n=1}^{N^2} n^{-s} \sum_{d | n, d \le N, n/d \le N} \mu(d) = 1 + \sum_{n = N+1}^{N^2}n^{-s}\sum_{d | n, d \le N,n/d \le N} \mu(d) \ne 1$$

Hence $\sum_{n = 1}^N n^{-s} \sim f(N)$ doesn't imply that $\sum_{n = 1}^N \mu(n) n^{-s} \sim \frac{1}{f(N)}$